# API mais adequada - OpenGL ES 2.0 x Canvas x Drawable

Tags: android, canvas, drawable, opengl

Bom dia,

Gostaria de fazer um aplicativo para Android para fazer o seguinte: exibir a planta de uma casa no celular, e ao usuário tocar em um cômodo na tela, a cor do cômodo mudar.

Eu estou familizarizado com OpenGL ES 2.0, e acho que é uma ferramenta excelente para gráficos, mas nunca mexi ainda com o Canvas e Drawable.

Qual é a API mais indicada para eu utilizar em meu aplicativo?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 1):

**OpenGL x Canvas**

OpenGL lhe dará controle total sobre os gráficos que você está usando. Você não vai ter muitas limitações a longo prazo sobre o que você gostaria de fazer. Você pode fazer um bom projeto em 3D em um Android usando OpenGL, como você pode processar grandes quantidades de polígonos e sobrepor gráficos 2D em cima de qualquer coisa. É uma grande quantidade de trabalho, no entanto.

A principal diferença é que o OpenGL é muito mais rápido em comparação com Canvas (Gráficos 2D Android desenho de superfície). Embora a aceleração de hardware está habilitado para Canvas, é um pouco difícil de usá-lo de forma eficaz.

Canvas faz a vida mais fácil. É fácil de usar e simples de entender, mesmo para alguém novo para a Computação Gráfica.

No final, vai depender do que você precisa fazer. Se você precisar de coisas extravagantes como Geometria, iluminação etc, então você deve definitivamente ir para OpenGL. Além disso, se você precisa, em seguida, OpenGL 3D é a sua única opção, uma vez Canvas só suporta gráficos 2D.

*Drawble:* Uma maneira simples de adicionar gráficos a sua aplicação fazendo referência a um arquivo de imagem a partir de seus recursos do projeto. Tipos de arquivos suportados são PNG (preferencial), JPG (aceitável) e GIF (desanimado). Esta técnica seria obviamente preferido para ícones de aplicação, logos ou outros gráficos, tais como os utilizados em um jogo.

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Fonte: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html